# If it is unachievable, why do we need 'utopia' and utopian thinking?

Tags: habermas, bloch, utopia

> Utopian anticipation plays an ambiguous role in Bloch’s philosophy. On
> the one hand, it attaches special meanings to different elements of
> material and social reality, to various fragments of nature and
> history and thus serves, teleologically, as a unifying normative force
> (1951 [GA 8: 487]), sometimes creating the impression that Bloch
> overemphasizes the unity of futurity for its own sake (Eagleton 2015).
> On the other hand, it suspends any given form or entity as
> experimental and preliminary, emphasizes the risk of fetishizing the
> utopian goal, the teleology of the pre-given plan, and insists on the
> impossibility to fully construe the new from the old, on radical
> incompleteness of any achieved state or any present process (Lyotard
> 1976). The problem of the absolute is re-stated by Bloch as the
> non-availability of the future and even of the tools to fully grasp
> it. Crucially, this incompleteness also entails a permanent risk of
> failure, which again, dialectically, is just an opposite side of a
> fundamental instability and mutability of our world (Bloch
> characteristically calls things Auszugsgestalten ihrer selbst, “forms
> of departure from themselves” [Bloch 1954–59 [1986a: 1345]]). In this
> sense, the question: where does utopia go? Or What is the
> eschatological aim of the utopian process?—is both necessary and
> unanswerable. It should be asked for defining the normative
> orientation of hope and for establishing a proper critical function of
> “concrete utopia”. But its answer is never perfect, either. In the
> state of absolute fulfillment, there is no place for utopian
> philosophy. This philosophy is subject to its own critical scrutiny,
> its aims are only formulated in the process, and its business itself
> is never complete. That is why the original title of The Principle of
> Hope was Dreams of a Better Life, not of a best life. This negative
> dialectical vision makes Bloch not a Hegelian of a system (indeed, he
> attacked “the system” when it was associated with East European
> “socialist” unfreedom), but a Hegelian of a promise.

I assume it does not make for some state of beatitude for its proponents. For whom is it just there to safeguard against reaction?

> The function of the spiritual leaders, the agents of creativity, is
> not to impose their genius on others, but to open up an anticipatory
> space of redemption (die Sache selbst, GA 10: 209) and share with the
> utopian community the practices and possibilities of this
> incompleteness, a yet “hidden human face” (GA 10: 210) of an
> individual.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/bloch/

More specifically, does it allow for some sort of communicative rationality, and how or in what sense at all?

> view of reason is concerned with clarifying the norms and procedures
> by which agreement can be reached, and is therefore a view of reason
> as a form of public justification.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicative_rationality

Is there anything particularly important in bearing in mind if you were to link Bloch with Habermas?

Comment: That question reminds me of the John Wooden quote (famous American basketball coach, also famous for his motivational quotes) _"Make every day your masterpiece."_ He's not expecting you to **achieve** that, but motivating you to **strive** for it (similar to @NotThatGuy's answer below). He was a coach, after all. So Utopia's just a (likely unachievable) goal, the bullseye you're aiming for on the target of life, so to speak. But don't worry about missing that bullseye... another of John Wooden's terrific quotes: _"If you're not making mistakes, then you're not doing anything."_

Answer (score 1):

Utopias represent ideals that we strive towards.

We can still try to get *closer* some utopia, even if we can never ultimately reach it.

For example, we may have some ideal where everyone is treated equally, has equal opportunity, and is rewarded proportionally based on their effort and their contribution to society. Now, even if we can't fully reach that, we can still say e.g. we shouldn't enslave other human beings, everyone should have access to basic education, blatant discrimination should be unlawful, etc. There may be other ways to conclude those things, but merely striving towards the ideal of equality would lead you there. It would lead you to a *more equal* society, even if you never get to a *perfectly equal* society.

There are additional considerations:

- Hope and dreams.

  It may be somewhat of a false hope, but there may still be some utility to envisioning a utopia, purely because doing so brings us some joy.
- Lack of knowledge.

  Given our current level of knowledge, we may see a certain limit for how close we can get to a certain ideal. We may set that as our ultimate goal. As our knowledge increases, that limit may disappear, but our goal may remain, and that may impede us from progressing beyond the original believed limit.
- Things change.

  Related to the point above, society today looks very different from society a few years ago. And you probably don't have to go back even a decade to see significant changes (not that all of them are necessarily good). The past few decades had huge changes with the rise of the internet and social media, and many people can't even fathom how things worked before that. Never mind if you go back centuries or millennia, during which we had huge advancements in science, infrastructure and morality.

  I wouldn't trust that someone who lives a few centuries or millennia would be able to present meaningful goals for life in modern times, but they can nonetheless speak of ideals that still apply in the modern day.

  A more specific goal may be more actionable, but an ideal is more general and timeless.

  This is especially relevant given that humanity tends to put a lot of value into the words of our ancestors. This may be justified to some degree, as you can only gather so much knowledge in one generation. But we may also put a bit too much value into their words. So it could help to question the underlying ideals in what people say, to ask how consistent what they say is with those ideals, especially in the modern day, and to contextualise what we promote ourselves in the form of ideals.